# No read/write access on files on merged Directory

Tags: c, macos, directory

I am working on a project for uni were we have to merge the contents of one or more directories into a single output directory, and my project works seemingly perfectly except, files outputted in the output directory have no read or write access, i can change it manually but i am assuming this is not the desired solution, i am fairly new to c and OSX so it could be a very easy fix,

I am currently using 0777 for the mode_t parameter of my mkdir function
and opening all the files with O_RDWR.

Comment: I don't recommend 0777 mode for directories; 0755 would usually be safer.  For the files, what's your umask value set to?  When you create the file, what's the third argument to `open()` — or the second argument to `creat()`?

Comment: ok i will change the value to 0755, i am using open twice, once to make an int for the source e.g int src =open(source_name,O_RWRW) and int dest= open(file_name, O_CREAT|O_RDRW) i dont use creat() at all

Comment: Are you moving the files or copying them (i.e. do you open/create read/write in order to copy the contents)?

Comment: Your problem is that you have a quasi-random value being used for the file mode (permissions) when you create the files using `open()` and `O_CREAT`.  That requires a third argument — the file mode. The formal prototype for [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) is unusual; it is a varargs function `int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...)`.  When you use `O_CREAT`, the third argument becomes necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `int dest= open(file_name, O_CREAT|O_RDRW)` is wrong. 
When you specify O_CREAT as a flag, [open](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/open.2.html)() expects you to provide a third argument, the permission bits.

This means you have to do e.g. `int dest= open(file_name, O_CREAT|O_RDRW, 0755);`. Since you're copying files, you could read the existing permission of that file using [stat](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/stat.2.html)() , and provide the same permissions when you open and create the destination file.

Remember also that file permission bits when creating a new file are affected by the [umask](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/umask.2.html) , you might want to call `umask(0);` before copying files if you copy over the existing permission bits, so you always get the same permissions as the original file.